# Odd "Dependency property field missing" error

Tags: wpf, xaml, resharper, dependency-properties

ReSharper complains about the following XAML:

```
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsSelectionBoxHighlighted" Value="true"/>
              <Condition Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

The control template is, of course, for a `ComboBox`. With Solution-wide inspections on, Resharper reports a `Dependency property field missing` error on `IsSelectionBoxHighlighted`, but not on `IsDropDownOpen`. The only difference I can possibly come up with is that `IsSelectionBoxHighlighted` is read-only, but should that make a difference in this instance?

Is this a Resharper bug, or is something else going on here? Does this look familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsSelectionBoxHighlighted is not a DependencyProperty on the System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox class`, instead it appears to be an accessor for the Selected ComboBoxItem, in which the DependencyProperty is called IsHighlighted.

`The property targeted by your Trigger must be a Dependency Property`

Also check out [this bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-287481?query=%27a)

Comment: That makes sense, in a very annoying way :-)  So how the heck do I use it as a trigger?

Comment: To wit, from the documentation: This property is a dependency property. However, the dependency property identifier field for IsSelectionBoxHighlighted is not public. Therefore, you cannot use the backing dependency property for property system operations that require the dependency property identifier, such as calls to GetValue. However, you can still use IsSelectionBoxHighlighted as a property trigger.